# On weaker and stronger topologies

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I have the following question:-

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on a set $X$ such that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$.Then are the followings true?

$(a)$ If $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence in $(X,\tau_2)$,then it is convergent in $(X,\tau_1)$

$(b)$The identity map $I:(X,\tau_1)\rightarrow (X,\tau_2)$ is continous

My thoughts:

For $(a)$ Though I could not show it to be true or false but I realise that the converse is not true by taking $X=\mathbb{R}$, $x_n=\frac1n\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\tau_1=$ usual topology and $\tau_2=$discrete topology.

For $(b)$ I think it is false. Because when $\tau_1\subsetneq \tau_2$, there is at least one open set $O\in \tau_2\setminus \tau_1$ whose inverse image under the identity map in $(X,\tau_1)$ is $O$ itself which is not open in $(X,\tau_1)$ by our choice. So it is false.Am I logically correct here?

Please help me . Thanks for sharing your knowledge and giving your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a)$ is obvious from the defintions,. Let $(x_n)$ converge to $x$ under $\tau_2$.

Then if $O$ is a $\tau_1$-open neighbourhood of $x$, $O$ is also a $\tau_2$-open neighbourhood of $x$ so contains a tail of the sequence. Hence $x_n \to x$ under $\tau_1$ too.

$(b)$: $I$ is continuous iff

$$\forall O \in \tau_2: I^{-1}[O] \in \tau_1$$

but as $I^{-1}[O]=O$ this just says $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$.
So **no** iff the inclusion is proper, **yes** iff the topologies are equal.

Answer (score 0):

a) Let $x_n \to x$ in $(X,\tau_2)$ and let $U$ be any open set in $(X,\tau_2)$ containing $x$. Then $U$ is also open in $(X,\tau_2)$, so $x_n \in U$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence a) is true.

Your answer for b) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

(a) is true. A proof is as follows:
Let $x \in X$ be any limit of $\{x_n\}$ in $(X, \tau_2)$. We show that $x_n\to x$ in $(X, \tau_1)$ as well.
For that, we need to show the following:
Given any open set $U \in \tau_1$ containing $x$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n > N$.
However, note that $U \in \tau_1 \implies U \in \tau_2$ and thus, the above follows since $x_n \to x$ in $(X, \tau_2)$.

---

(b) is true iff $\tau_1 = \tau_2$. The logic you gave was correct. In general, you can say the following:

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be any two topologies on $X$.
 $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ iff the identity map $I:(X, \tau_2) \to (X, \tau_1)$ is continuous.